# iOS: Programmatic way to tell whether or not push notifications are enabled

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an iPhone development application with `APNS` enabled for the `appID`. In my `applicationDidBecomeActive` event I check to see whether or not push notifications are enabled by doing the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

    //Check if remote notifications are enabled for this app, if not proceed with performSetupAndWebService calls
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

    if(types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        //User has push notifications DISABLED for this application.
        NSLog(@"PUSH NOTIFICATIONS DISABLED");

        [self performSetupAndWebServiceCalls];
    }
    else
    {
        //User has push notifications ENABLED for this application.
        NSLog(@"PUSH NOTIFICATIONS ENABLED");

        NSLog(@"Registering for push notifications...");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
```

It seems that no matter what I do, my code always tells me that push notifications are disabled. My app icon is in `Notification Center` in `Settings` and it is included. I have tried turning off specific types of notification and turning them back on but `types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone` is always true.

Am I missing something obvious? The bad thing is this seems to be affecting users of our production app as well, but not all of them. Very inconsistent and very frustrating.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

When notifications are disabled and you try to register for them you get the following `UIApplicationDelegate` method called:

```
application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

Comment: The thing is that delegate method doesn't always get called, which is why I put in the check in my `applicationDidBecomeActive` method. I've been down this road before, I've had times where neither `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` nor `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` get called.

Comment: IIRC either is eventually called, only they may return after a sadly unpredictable time. By the way the Apple doc on `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` says: "These types are first set when the app calls the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method to register itself with Apple Push Notification Service.". My guess is you expect a different semantic, like "current user-selected types". They probably mean "currently registered types on the APNS", and if it's the case your code never registers for any type.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) getpushNotificationstatus
 {
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
 {
 return ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]); 
} 
else 
{
 UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplicationy sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]; return (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert); 
}
}
```

It will work in iOS8 as well